# PHP connect to AIM TOC

Tags: php, bots, aol, aim, oscar-protocol

In the middle of 2010, I found a class library called **PHPToCLib**. It ran flawlessly for over a year - I was able to implement a tremendous amount of my own, custom code into a an AIM Bot that I could run from my CMD Prompt. However, near the end of 2011, the servers stopped responding to the script. It connects to **toc.oscar.aol.com** on port **5190**, and that hasn't been changed. I am indeed aware that AOL discontinued their TOC2 servers and that it's not possible to connect with them anymore. However, I downloaded a program called **[TerraIM](https://terraim.en.softonic.com/)** that uses the same specifications and is somehow able to connect to them. I was wondering if there were any updates on how I could get my script to connect, and if so, what do I need to change?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe TOC2 is still available.  Got a link to that library you're using?  Maybe it only used the original TOC protocol?  There is always OSCAR, which is decently documented... but only appropriate for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

TerraIM also supports the OSCAR protocol which I assume it's defaulting to. If you are working with IM bots the absolute best way to go is to leverage libpurple.  Unfortunately there is not a good PHP binding to libpurple.  There are a couple python bindings.  If you don't wish to migrate your code, there is an implementation that provides an HTTP interface which may be easy to integrate with depending on your use case.  Alternatively, you could use thrift to comminute between your existing PHP code and the python bindings -- this would require a bit more coding than leveraging an HTTP interface.  Here are some resources you may find helpful:

Python bindings:

github.com/fahhem/python-purple

github.com/Raptr/Heliotrope

HTTP interface from HTTP binding:

github.com/atamurad/http-purple

Thrift:

http://thrift.apache.org/